# Country Specific Magento Product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.6

I want setup a magento store based on country.

Each product is assigned to one of the country from the list. In the store view, product should appear based on the selected country (like language switching).

How can this be done by using magento ?

Answer (score 2):

Make a category for each country and put the correct product in the correct category. In System > Manage Stores you can add stores. Add a store for each country. Set the store root category to the correct category. Make sure that the correct Store is loaded based on visitor country. Now every country has its own products.